# How do I select the parent of a specific type of element?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Product Name
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Apple
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Dell
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        HP
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

From the above HTML code I should be able to do something like:

```
page.search('td').text_includes('HP').last.up('tbody')
```

I can do this by calling `parent` several times on that `<td>`, but I want to traverse up until I find `<tbody>` and get that element. jQuery has this ability, but I am not sure how to do this with Nokogiri.

Comment: Does the raw HTML really have a `<tbody>` tag or is the browser you used inserting it? That particular tag is rarely seen in the wild but browsers pretend it's there. This is a common problem when trying to parse HTML tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going with:

```
page.at('td[text()*="HP"]').ancestors('tbody')[0]
```

Comment: +1. Readable and clean. I give it an 8 because I can dance to it.

Answer (score 2):

XPath makes this a lot easier

```
tbody = page.xpath '//tbody[tr/td[contains(.,"HP")]]'
```

Comment: True but html people like to use css

Comment: @pguardiario: Having a penchant for the wrong tool is no excuse for using it.

Comment: Css is the wrong tool to use with html? I'll believe that if I ever see a stylesheet written in xpath :)

Comment: @pguardino: Unfortunately, to get CSS property declarations you need to apply CSS selectors. I'm sure there are many people who would be happy to have XPath selectors instead. Having seen what XPath can do, CSS is getting more and more close to the same functionality with a different syntax. Neither the `text()` pseudo-attribute nor the `ancestors` of your own solution would be possible even with CSS3.

Comment: Ok, I agree that css has close to the same functionality as xpath, but is generally better for html. Sounds like we agree.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
page.search('td').text_includes('HP').xpath('./ancestor::tbody[1]')
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Nokogiri equivalent of jQuery closest() method for finding first matching ancestor in tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003215/nokogiri-equivalent-of-jquery-closest-method-for-finding-first-matching-ancest)

so for example:

```
src = (element.ancestors('table').first || { })['src']
```

or in rails:

```
src = element.ancestors('table').first.try(:fetch, 'src')
```